# How to add ' to generated link in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
$output .= '<a class="dropdown-toggle has-category" data-toggle="dropdown" href="'.$this->getLink($menu).'" target="'.$menu['target'].'">';
```

I have php file with this code `href="'.$this->getLink($menu).'"`

its generates in html this `href="https://www.myweb.com/"`

Now i need to do it with onClick so that the output turned out like this

```
onclick="location.href='https://www.myweb.com'"
```

Changed php code `onclick="location.href='.$this->getLink($menu).'"`

and result is `onclick="location.href=https://www.myweb.com"`
Link not working cuz lacks '
Can someone help me?

Comment: Please show the COMPLETE string concatenation code line. It all depends on what you are starting the string literal with as to how you do it

Comment: Add needed code

Comment: Go learn syntax basics. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
onclick="location.href=\''.$this->getLink($menu).'\'">
```

**Example:-**

```
echo '<a onclick="location.href=\''.$this->getLink($menu).'\'">';
```

Comment: onclick="location.href=\''.$this->getLink($menu).'\'" Working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this escaped single quote: `\'`?

```php
echo '...onclick="location.href='.$this->getLink($menu).'\'"...';
```

(I added the `echo` to complete the code example).

Comment: I dont have experience with PHP and just started to study it, but whis issue needed to be resolved as fast as possible. Any way thx for attention